# Android: RecyclerView patrón repetido a lo largo de la lista

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Estoy trabajando con un `RecyclerView` y estoy teniendo el clásico problema que vi antes en un `ListView`.

Cuando se tienen imágenes (logos), botones, checkbox, etc. dentro de un item de un `ListView` éste reutiliza las vistas y por ende repite estos item a través de toda la lista. Pero en este caso me está pasando con un `RecyclerView` y la verdad no entiendo porqué, ya que he seguido al pie de la letra las recomendaciones para el uso del componente (o quizá no)

Les comparto el `Adapter` que tengo trabajado, la data esta correcta; no tengo problema, el problema es que; basado en un indicativo de procesado debo ocultar un botón, al momento de escribir este post solo he procesado un registro por lo que es el único que debe estar sin botón, pero el patrón de los botones no se muestra correctamente.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Medidor> medidores;

    // Pass in the contact array into the constructor
    public Adapter(List<Medidor> medidores) {
        this.medidores = medidores;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View medidorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cargar_lista_medidores, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(medidorView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Medidor medidor = medidores.get(position);
        TextView direccion = holder.direccion;
        TextView numero = holder.numero;
        ImageButton button = holder.button;

        direccion.setText(medidor.getDireccion()); //trabaja perfecto
        numero.setText(medidor.getSecReg() + " - " + medidor.getNumApa()); //trabaja perfecto

        if (medidor.getIndicativo().equals("1")) {
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //No refleja en el boton el estado correcto
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return medidores.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView direccion;
        TextView numero;
        ImageButton button;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            direccion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.direccionMedidor);
            numero = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numMedidor);
            button = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_tomaLectura);
        }
    }
}
```

Y aquí les muestro una imagen de lo que está sucediendo. Imagino que debe ser una tontada, pero no la encuentro :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, que propiedad de visibilidad tiene el elemento imageButton_tomaLectura en tu layout?

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo he descubierto yo mismo. No sé porqué, pero con los `ListView` no pasaba esto.

He notado que lo que debe hacerse es establecer el estado por defecto del componente (no importa el definido en el XML) y que a partir de este estado "default" se realicen los cambios de ser necesarios, aplicaría para cualquier otro componente (checkbox, imagen, etc.)

Añadí el estado por defecto del botón antes de las validaciones de estado y ha funcionado correctamente.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Medidor medidor = medidores.get(position);
    TextView direccion = holder.direccion;
    TextView numero = holder.numero;
    ImageButton button = holder.button;

    //**** AÑADO ESTADO DEFAULT DEL COMPONENTE ****
    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    direccion.setText(medidor.getDireccion());
    numero.setText(medidor.getSecReg() + " - " + medidor.getNumApa()); 

    if (medidor.getIndicativo().equals("1")) {
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
    }
}
```

No pasa lo mismo con los `TextView` porque a todos se les asigna un contenido diferente en cada iteración para llenar la información de los items. Al menos eso es lo que me parece.

Answer (score 1):

Si creaste un `ViewHolder`, debes acceder a sus propiedades directamente dentro de `onBindViewHolder()`, no debes crear otra instancia del elemento, además el estado de los elementos dentro del `viewHolder` nunca se guarda en el XML, debes estar consiente que estas modificando la propiedad de visibilidad del boton dependiendo de `medidor.getIndicativo().equals("1")` :

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Medidor medidor = medidores.get(position);
       /* TextView direccion = holder.direccion;
        TextView numero = holder.numero;
        ImageButton button = holder.button;*/

        holder.direccion.setText(medidor.getDireccion()); //trabaja perfecto
        holder.numero.setText(medidor.getSecReg() + " - " + medidor.getNumApa()); //trabaja perfecto

        holder.button.setVisibility(medidor.getIndicativo().equals("1") ? View.INVISIBLE: View.GONE); //No refleja en el boton el estado correcto

      /*  if (medidor.getIndicativo().equals("1")) {
            holder.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //No refleja en el boton el estado correcto
        }*/
    }
```

Asegura en tu Layout, que la propiedad del botón sea visible por default.

Comment: Es buen punto, lo revisaré.